# Why slack slash command returns "http_client_error"

Tags: node.js, chatbot, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to build a very simple Slackbot using the [Bolt Framework](https://github.com/SlackAPI/bolt). I'm using ngrok to run this locally and when I invoke a slash command, ngrok just shows:

[image: screengrab of ngrok]
[image: screenshot of slack]

According to the Bot documentation, the app uses `app.command()` to handle slash commands. This is part of my code:

```
const {App, LogLevel} = require("@slack/bolt");

const app = new App({
  token: "XXXX",
  signingSecret: "XXXX",
  logLevel: LogLevel.DEBUG
});

// The echo command simply echoes on command
app.command("/standup", async ({command, ack, say}) => {
  // Acknowledge command request

  ack();
  say(`${command.text}`);
  console.log("Entered into the app.command for /standUp");
});
```

Within Slack, the slash command is configured like this:

[image: slack_setup]

The bot works when interacting with messages, but just does receive and respond to Slash commands. I'm really new to this so any info would be great or just a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. When I was trying above, I had the request url end with `../command`, but it needed to stay the same as the configuration for Event Subscriptions with `../slack/events/`.

I started to receive the commands after I made this change. As far as I can tell, this was not documented very well on Slack's docs, but I figured out the issue by seeing the configuration [here](https://github.com/seratch/bolt-starter) and lots of trial and error. :)

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this! I had the same issue and now it works! Definitely not well documented on Slack's part, especially considering that the placeholder on the URL input box under the slash commands configuration says "https://example.com/slack/command"

Comment: I have the same problem, so instead of using `http://4292f9da.ngrok.io/total-yesterday` I need to use `http://4292f9da.ngrok.io/slack/events/`?

Comment: This didn't work for me. I've tried the same slack events and a custom domain with both http and https.